# How to read build-in documentation in lua?

Tags: lua

In python you can do `help(str)` to read the corresponding build-in docs in the interpreter. If I try the same in lua interpreter:

```
> help(str)
stdin:1: attempt to call global 'help' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

How can I read the build-in lua docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built-in docs in Lua. Read the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/).

The closest thing to built-in docs is table dumps. For instance, to know which math functions are available, do

```
for k,v in pairs(math) do
   print(k,v)
end
```